# How do I solve this error in node:sj: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, error-handling

Being new to java script and node.js, I ran into an error.

I'm attempting to scrape newspaper articles from a french newspaper using password and serchterms.

This is the code I'm using:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const jsonTab = []; // We create our table

function writeFile() {
  // Will write the json file
  fs.writeFile("output.json", JSON.stringify(jsonTab, null, 4), (err) => {
    console.log("File successfully written!");
  });
}

// The URL of the advanced search feature with our keywords
const url = 'http://www.lemonde.fr/recherche/?keywords="Rap+"+"hip-hop"+"hip%20hop"+"rappeur"+"rappeurs"+"raps"+"rappers"&page_num=1&operator=or&exclude_keywords=&qt=recherche_texte_title&author=&period=custom_date&start_day=01&start_month=01&start_year=1970&end_day=20&end_month=09&end_year=2017&sort=asc';

/* The first request call, our goal here is to get the number of results and then
to calculate the number of pages */
request(url, (error, response, html) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  // All the variables we will use later
  let number;
  let description;
  let date;
  let title;
  let link;

  if (!error) {
    $(".bg_gris_clair").filter(() => {
      /* We want to select all the HTML
      elements with the class ".bg_gris_clair" (and we already know there is
      only one) */
      const data = $(this);
      const str = data.children("strong").text().trim();
      number = parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("e")).replace(/\s/g, ""), 10);
    });
  }

  let count = 1;

  for (let i = 1; i <= number / 10; i++) {
    const urlPerPage = 'http://www.lemonde.fr/recherche/?keywords="Rap+"+"hip-hop"+"hip%20hop"+"rappeur"+"rappeurs"+"raps"+"rappers"&page_num=' + i + "&operator=or&exclude_keywords=&qt=recherche_texte_title&author=&period=custom_date&start_day=01&start_month=01&start_year=1970&end_day=20&end_month=09&end_year=2017&sort=asc";

    request(urlPerPage, (err, response2, html2) => {
      if (!err) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html2);

        $(".grid_11.omega.resultat").filter(() => {
          const json = {
            date: "",
            title: "",
            description: "",
            url: ""
          };
          const data = $(this);

          title = data.children("h3").children("a").text().trim();
          link = "http://lemonde.fr" + data.children("h3").children("a").attr("href").trim();
          description = data.children("p").text().trim();
          const dateStr = data.children("span").text();
          date = dateStr.replace(/.+?(?=\d)/, "");

          json.title = title;
          json.url = link;
          json.description = description;
          json.date = date;
          jsonTab.push(json);
        });
      } else if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      count += 1;

      // Write the file once we iterated through all the pages.
      if (count === parseInt(number / 10, 10)) {
        writeFile();
      }
    });
  }
});

const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

// Prepare all the variables needed later
let count = 0;
let timeout = 0;
const id = "myusername";
const mdp = "mypassword";
let obj;

// The URLs we will scrape from
const connexionUrl = "https://secure.lemonde.fr/sfuser/connexion";

// Will write an "output.json" file
function writeFile() {
  fs.writeFile("output.json", JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4), (err) => {
    console.log(
      "File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file"
    );
  });
}

// creating a clean jar to store the cookies
const j = request.jar();

// First Get Request Call
request(
  {
    url: connexionUrl,
    jar: j
  },
  (err, httpResponse, html) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    // We use Cheerio to load the HTML and be able to find the connection__token
    const token = $("#connection__token")[0].attribs.value; // here is the connection__token

    // Construction of the form required in the POST request to login
    const form = {
      "connection[mail]": id,
      "connection[password]": mdp,
      "connection[stay_connected]": 1,
      "connection[save]": "",
      "connection[_token]": token
    };

    // POST REQUEST to Log IN. Same url with "request headers" and the complete form.
    request.post(
      {
        url: connexionUrl,
        jar: j,
        headers: {
          Accept:
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            Origin: "http://secure.lemonde.fr/",
            Host: "secure.lemonde.fr",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
            "User-Agents":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0",
          Connection: "keep-alive",
          Pragma: "no-cache",
          Referer: "https://secure.lemonde.fr/sfuser/connexion"
        },

        form: form
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        // WE ARE CONNECTED :D

        /* Second GET request call : this time, we use the response of the POST
        request to request the right URL */
        request(
          {
            url: response.headers.location,
            jar: j
          },
          (err, httpResponse, html2) => {
            const json = fs.readFileSync("./firstStep.json"); // Load the JSON created in step one
            obj = JSON.parse(json); // We create our JSON in a usable javascript object

            // forEach loop to iterate through all the object and request each link
            obj.forEach((e) => {
              let articleUrl = e.url;

              /* We use a setTimeout to be sure that all the requests are performed
              one by one and not all at the same time */
              setTimeout(() => {
                request(
                  {
                    url: articleUrl,
                    jar: j
                  },
                  (error1, httpResponse, html3) => {
                    if (!error1) {
                      const $ = cheerio.load(html3); // load the HTML of the article page
                      $(".contenu_article.js_article_body").filter(() => {
                        const data = $(this);

                        // get the content, remove all the new lines (better for Excel)
                        let text = data
                          .text()
                          .trim()
                          .replace(/\n/g, "\t");

                        e.text = text; // push the content in the table
                      });

                      $(".txt3.description-article").filter(() => {
                        const data = $(this);

                        const description = data
                          .text()
                          .trim()
                          .replace(/\n/g, "\t");

                        e.description = description;
                      });
                    }
                  }
                );

                count += 1;

                // Write a new JSON file once we get the content of all the articles
                if (count === obj.length) {
                  writeFile();
                }
              }, timeout);

              timeout += 50; // increase the timeout length each time
            });
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Running step3 it throws an error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './firstStep.json'

The tutorial can be found here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-scraped-7000-articles-from-a-newspaper-website-using-node-1309133a5070/

I am more used to using R, this is a new playing field for me.
I suspect the problem is straight forward, and related to the directory.

Thank you

Comment: We'd need more information about your files. Where's this file `firstStep.json` located? Is it on the same directory as this js file?

Comment: It appears to not be created when searching for it manually. Im more familiar with R. I expect node.js to work the same way, and that way it will try and save in the directory it's set to

Comment: Even so, you must have an idea of **where** you want the file... otherwise loading the file is impossible. String paths that are relative are resolved against the process current working directory and are not relative to the js file that tries to read/write to it.

Comment: Also, if you can't find the file manually anywhere, you probably don't have that file in the first place. Unless this script also deletes the file somewhere else. Node will throw an error if the file does not indeed exist.

Comment: I would like the file to be placed where the the code later look for it. I'm a university student, and coding is not something im that familiar with so excuse me, you lost me at the end. Does that mean the code have not been constructed in a way where it creates the file it self? (The daat are the scraped newspaper articles)

Comment: Well then you'll have to clarify what you think your code does. Looks like it was copied and paste again and that's certainly not the way to work with node. For example there's two functions with the same name `writeFile` they each clobber each other. Your script writes to `output.json` so maybe that's what you want instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.